# How to add value into a map which is stored in another map?

Tags: apex, soql, map

```java
Map<Id, SObject> accQuery = new Map<Id, SObject>();
Map<string, Map<Id, SObject>> queriesList = new Map<string, Map<Id, SObject>>();

queriesList.put('select * from account where Id IN: AccountMap.values()',accQuery);
    
for(string queries : queriesList.keySet()){
    string transformedQuery = QueryUtil.getTransformedQueryStr(queries,fieldsToBlacklist);
    system.debug('Query is '+transformedQuery);// Changes the query to "select id, isdeleted, masterrecordid, name, type....from account where...."

    //I want to add database.query records into accQuery Map
    queriesList.get(queries) = new Map<Id,SObject>((List<SObject>)database.query(transformedQuery));
 //I am getting error in above line

}
```

I am not able to insert a value and getting error

> A value cannot be assigned to an expression.

I tried so many other ways, but no luck. **My main goal is to add values of database.query into accQuery**

Comment: Please edit your question to include on what line you are getting the error.

Comment: You should review the documentation on the [`Map`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#!) class, where you'll find the `put()` method. Note also that `SELECT *` is not valid SOQL, nor can you use complex Apex expressions in dynamic SOQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking time to try to understand the error message you're getting will help you understand how to move forward.

Although you have paraphrased the error and not included the stack trace (when asking about errors, you should *never* try to shorten it or paraphrase it. You don't know what the important part of the error is, and have a fair chance of leaving out vital information), it's pretty clear to experienced eyes that the issue is the following line

`queriesList.get(queries) = new Map<Id,SObject>((List<SObject>)database.query(transformedQuery));`

#### Explaining the error

The `queriesList.get()` part evaluates to a map, so that line of code ends up being
`[A Map] = [A different Map];`
which is not valid syntax (hence your error).

Variables can be assigned, but what you have here isn't a variable, it's an instance of a Map object.

#### Correcting that line of code

Instead of attempting to use the assignment operator, since you're working on an instance of a Map, you should be using one of the methods offered by the Map class.

The `putAll()` method can take a list of SObjects when the map is a `Map<Id, SObject>` (as you have), so that's what you should use here.

You also are doing some unnecessary casting (`database.query()` already returns a `List<SObject>`), so in the end you want that line to be something like
`queriesList.get(queries).putAll(database.query(transformedQuery));`

#### Other considerations

Your variable naming needs improvement. `queriesList` is a Map, not a List, and `accQuery` isn't a helpful description (it doesn't tell you what its purpose is)

Also, be aware that collections stored inside of collections are stored *by reference*. That means that right now, each query you store in your `queriesList` is storing the *same map instance*. If you have more than one query, the results for each individual query would appear in the map for *every* query string key.

At the very least, you would want to `.clone()` your `accQuery` map when you `.put()` a new query into the `queriesList` map.

Cloning gives you an independent copy, so that each map stored by the query template would only store the results of that *one* query.